# excel data compareing base on fixed value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data like below in a excel sheet with added a extra column value "PRE" and "POST" , In  "POST" section there is some data deleted , how do i find out the deleted record by comparing with "PRE" value.? i hava huge record to compare with..

```
    EMPNO   ENAME   JOB MGR HIREDATE    SAL COMM    DEPTNO
pre 7369    SMITH   CLERK   7902    17-Dec-80   800     20
pre 7499    ALLEN   SALESMAN    7698    20-Feb-81   1600    300 30
pre 7521    WARD    SALESMAN    7698    22-Feb-81   1250    500 30
pre 7566    JONES   MANAGER 7839    2-Apr-81    2975        20
pre 7654    MARTIN  SALESMAN    7698    28-Sep-81   1250    1400    30
pre 7698    BLAKE   MANAGER 7839    1-May-81    2850        30
pre 7782    CLARK   MANAGER 7839    9-Jun-81    2450        10
pre 7788    SCOTT   ANALYST 7566    9-Dec-82    3000        20
pre 7839    KING    PRESIDENT       17-Nov-81   5000        10
pre 7844    TURNER  SALESMAN    7698    8-Sep-81    1500    0   30
pre 7876    ADAMS   CLERK   7788    12-Jan-83   1100        20
pre 7900    JAMES   CLERK   7698    3-Dec-81    950     30
pre 7902    FORD    ANALYST 7566    3-Dec-81    3000        20
pre 7934    MILLER  CLERK   7782    23-Jan-82   1300        10

post    7369    SMITH   CLERK   7902    17-Dec-80   800     20
post    7499    ALLEN   SALESMAN    7698    20-Feb-81   1600    300 30
post    7521    WARD    SALESMAN    7698    22-Feb-81   1250    500 30
post    7566    JONES   MANAGER 7839    2-Apr-81    2975        20
post    7654    MARTIN  SALESMAN    7698    28-Sep-81   1250    1400    30
post    7698    BLAKE   MANAGER 7839    1-May-81    2850        30
```

Comment: yes Empno is unique..

Answer (score 0):

Select the EmpNo column and apply Conditional Formatting 
Highlight Cells Rules --> Duplicate Values --> Select 'Unique' from 'Format cells that contain' Dropdown--> Choose 'Value with' --> Ok.

You can find out the deleted records easily. 
If you want to see as a group of deleted records, Use 'Sort by Color' option

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in column `J` *(from cell `J2` to the last record)*

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B:$B,$B8)=1,"Deleted","")
```